# How to display in JSP a list obtained from Hibernate query

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, struts2, ognl

I am creating an struts hibernate application. I have obtained a list using hibernate query and passed it in action class. But I don't know how to display it in JSP.

I have successfully getting the list on the basis of query.
Now I want to display this list in JSP.

I have posted `struts.xml` and the JSP for showing result also.
Kindly check. But in JSP nothing is showing up.
I am using `s:iterate` to show the list. But no luck.
Even I have tried printing simple text under `s:iterate`, just for testing.
But it is also not showing up.

**POJO class:**

```
package org.sachin.Model;

import java.sql.Date;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;

@Entity
@Table(name="feed")
public class FeedBack {

private FeedBack feedback;
 private int taste;
 private int waiter;
 private int infra;
 private int price;

 private int id;

 private Date date=new java.sql.Date(new java.util.Date().getTime());
public int getTaste() {
    return taste;
}
public void setTaste(int taste) {
    this.taste = taste;
}
public int getWaiter() {
    return waiter;
}
public void setWaiter(int waiter) {
    this.waiter = waiter;
}
public int getInfra() {
    return infra;
}
public void setInfra(int infra) {
    this.infra = infra;
}
public int getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(int price) {
    this.price = price;
}
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}


@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
public Date getDate() {
    return date;
}
public void setDate(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
}
public FeedBack getFeedback() {
    return feedback;
}
public void setFeedback(FeedBack feedback) {
    this.feedback = feedback;
}


}
```

**Action Class:**

```
package org.sachin.action;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.sachin.Model.Datepicker;
import org.sachin.Model.FeedBack;
import org.sachin.hibernate.DateSpecific;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

public class SelectDateAction extends ActionSupport {

    /**
     * 
     */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8922465133057293868L;
private Datepicker datepicker;
private List<FeedBack> list =new ArrayList<>();;

    public List<FeedBack> getList() {
    return list;
}
public void setList(List<FeedBack> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
    public String execute(){

        String date=getDatepicker().getDate1();


        DateSpecific da=new DateSpecific();

         list=da.find(date);
         for(FeedBack feed:list){
             System.out.println("price");
             System.out.println(feed.getPrice());


         }

        System.out.println("hi"+date);

        return SUCCESS;
    }


    public Datepicker getDatepicker() {
        return datepicker;
    }
    public void setDatepicker(Datepicker datepicker) {
        this.datepicker = datepicker;
    }

}
```

**Hibernate class:**

```
public List<FeedBack> find(String Date) {


                //  Transaction t=session.beginTransaction(); 

            String SQL_QUERY = " from FeedBack where date='"+Date+"'";
            System.out.println("i am in hiber");
            System.out.println(SQL_QUERY);
            org.hibernate.Query query = session.createQuery(SQL_QUERY);
            List<FeedBack> list = query.list();
          for(FeedBack f:list){
              System.out.println("price");
              System.out.println(f.getPrice());
          }
            return list;

        }
```

This is my `struts.xml` in which all actions are defined.For now the action is `ByDate`.

**`struts.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>

    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="true" />
<!--    <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/ServletToExcludeFromStruts*" />
 -->
    <include file="login.xml"></include>
    <include file="AdminLogin.xml"></include>
    <include file="Feedback.xml"></include>
    <include file="NewUser.xml"></include>
    <include file="feedback.xml"></include>
    <include file="expression.xml"></include>
    <include file="logout.xml"></include>

    <package name="helloworld" namespace="/tut" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="add" class="org.sachin.action.EditAdminAction"
            method="execute">
            <result name="success">/JSP/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/JSP/AdminUserNameExists.jsp</result>

        </action>

    </package>

     <package name="serve" namespace="/tut" extends="struts-default">

        <action name="ByDate" class="org.sachin.action.SelectDateAction"
            method="execute">
            <result name="success" type="redirect">/JSP/iterate.jsp</result>
            <result name="error" type="redirect">/JSP/FeedBack.jsp</result>
            <result name="input" type="redirect">/JSP/Rateus.jsp</result>

        </action>
    </package>


</struts>
```

This is my JSP for showing list

**`iterate.jsp`:**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<s:form>
<body>
 <h1>Struts 2 Iterator tag example</h1>

<h3>Simple Iterator</h3>
<ol>
<s:iterator value="list">
 HE<li><s:property /></li>
</s:iterator>
</ol>
  </body>
  </s:form>
  </html>
```

I have successfully getting the list on the basis of query.
Now I want to display this list in JSP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [iterator](http://struts.apache.org/tag-developers/iterator-tag.html) tag:

> Iterator will iterate over a value. An iterable value can be any of:
>   `java.util.Collection`, `java.util.Iterator`, `java.util.Enumeration`,
>   `java.util.Map`, or an array.

**The code:**

```jsp
<s:iterator value="list"/>
  Price: <s:property value="price"/><br>
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: do i have to create getters and setter for fields like price?

Comment: i am confused about using iterator as even text price is not showing up Roman

Comment: is a jsp showing with struts tags? You should have getter for the `price` and if you are using inner class `FeedBack` the you should make it outer public class.

Comment: Post your JSP and `struts.xml`.

Comment: `s:form` should be inside the `body` tag. In the property tag use value that is a property of `FeedBack` object.

Comment: This is just one bug in your code but your code has plenty of them. Remove `type="redirect"` from the results.

Comment: Kindly suggest my bugs so i will take care of them in future

Comment: I can't count them: 1) (not a bug but...) Use package name lowercase so you can easy distinguish it from class 2) upgrade and update your `struts.xml` to the latest DTD version. 3) Use parameters in the query to avoid SQL injection 4) Don't use java.sql.Date because it cuts a time portion of date. 5) Implement `Preparable`  interface and populate list there before returning `"input"`result.

Comment: Thanks Roman,all points are clear..except last one about Preparable interface

Comment: You can search on SO using keywords Preparable and validation, sure you'll find plenty of answers.

Answer (score 1):

Please check with following code.

```
<s:iterator value="list" var="item"> 
<s:property value="%{#item.price}" /> 
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: Naveen then how can i print fields of list?

Comment: Sachin please try with this logic may be this will work.


   <s:iterator value="list" var="item">
   <s:property value="%{#item.price}" />
   </s:iterator>

Comment: Naveen not working man,Kindly review my action class.I think i am doing something wrong in there.Dont know much about how iterator works

Comment: Please share your list data with object data. override toString() method in FeedBack class and  then send your list data.

Answer (score 0):

you already globally declare `list variable`

```
  private List<FeedBack> list =new ArrayList<FeedBack>();//Getter & Setter Method.
```

and need Getter&Setter method of all.and remove your redeclartion in local.

`List<FeedBack> list = query.list();` change into `list = (List<FeedBack>)query.list();`  and  coversion should required.

add struts library in jsp page,Finally,

```
 <s:iterator value="list"/>
      Price: <s:property value="price"/><br>
 </s:iterator>
```

Comment: do i have to create getters and setters for price field?   And i am also confused about using s:iterator as even text price is not showing up.Please help